# Uncaught TypeError: $(...).sidebar is not a function but semantic.js is included in head

Tags: javascript, html, semantic-ui

I'm trying to implement the sidebar function for Semantic UI but I keep getting this error where it does not recognize the function

I've checked the network tab in Chrome and sure enough, when I comment out the jquery file, the semantic js file loads and vice versa. Not sure why

Below is my header

```
<head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Portal</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'portal/semantic.min.css' %}">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'portal/jquery-1.12.4.js' %}"</script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'portal/semantic.js' %}"></script>
        <style>
                body{
                        font-size:1.2em;
}
        </style>
        <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function(){
                        $(".ui.sidebar").sidebar("show");
                });
        </script>
</head>
```

Not quite sure why this happens. Maybe it is a simple mistake on my end. The help would be appreciated

Comment: Your script tag is not valid. You are missing the closing `>`

Comment: You forgot to close the first script tag.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, so the issue was that I didn't close the first script tag...yeesh